# Implementing Session authentication in django rest framework

Tags: django, authentication, session, django-rest-framework

I am trying to implement a session based auth in DRF.
I don't understand a thing from django session documentation as well as from DRF documentation.
I want to have an API endpoint for login , logout and one for listing all users.

```
class Login(APIView):

def post(self, request, format=None):
    email = request.POST.get("email", "")
    print(request.session)
    password = request.POST.get("password", "")
    user = authenticate(request,username=email,password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request,user)
        print(user)
        return Response('yes')
    else :
        return Response('No')


class UserList(APIView):
authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication,)
permission_classes = [
    IsAuthenticated,
    ]


def get(self, request, format=None):
    
    user = User.objects.all()
    print(request.user)
    serializer = UserSerializer(user, many=True)

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

I tried to call login API from browser.
Yes it logged in
Now when I try to call User list view I'm getting
Authentication details not provided error

My client server code (JS) for requesting users

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    console.log(Document.cookie);
    var urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();

    var requestOptions = {
      method: 'GET',
      credentials: 'include',
       headers: myHeaders,
      redirect: 'follow'
    };

    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/", requestOptions)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(result => console.log(result))
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Please help me understand sessions in DRF.

Comment: Try passing header from ajax   headers: {'X-CSRFToken':getCookie('csrftoken')
        ,'sessionid':getCookie('sessionid')
        },. I prefer token Authentication it is simple to use.

Comment: I tired but no luck.  And even request.session.test cookie is not working...